# Vue Router won't display components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm setting up a new Vue.js + Vue Router app and when I click on the router links set up in the App.vue, the content isn't showing up. The router and app objects are well defined, I've tried printing them. The app in the index.html is working since I can see the Bootstrap navbar.

Only the content of my views isn't showing up.

Main.js

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

import Vue from 'vue';
import app from './App.vue';

import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(app),
  router,
}).$mount('#app');
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Companies from './views/Companies.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/Companies',
      name: 'Companies',
      component: Companies,
    },
  ],
});
```

Companies.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="a">
    abcde
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Companies',
};
</script>
```

Edit : Ok that was the missing router view in app.vue! thanks

Comment: what does app.vue look like

Comment: Are you forgetting `<router-view>` in `App.vue`?

Comment: This is weird, it should work

Comment: Looks like you missed <router-view/> in your file as this lets the vue router know where to load the components for the specified path

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didnt see there was the router view tag. Happy new year :D